# No llena mi datagriview con linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

A consecuencia de mi primera consulta en este foro, me sugirieron usar EF, efectivamente estoy aprendiendo y me ahorra bastante tiempo en cuanto a las entidades, pero ahora tengo este problema.

Tengo 4 Capas Datos, Entidad, Negocio y Presentacion.

En mi cada Datos tengo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Entidad;

namespace Datos
{
    public class DPolizas
    {
        public List<POLIZAS> GetPolizas()
        {
                var Query = (from p in db.POLIZAS
                             select new POLIZAS
                             {
                                 ASE_CODIGO = p.ASE_CODIGO,
                                 CLI_CODIGO = p.CLI_CODIGO
                             }).ToList();

                return Query;
        }
    }
}
```

En mi capa Negocio tengo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Entidad;
using Datos;

namespace Negocio
{
    public class NPolizas
    {
        public List<POLIZAS> GetPolizas()
        {
            DPolizas dPolizas = new DPolizas();
            return dPolizas.GetPolizas();

        }
    }
}
```

y tengo un formulario con un datagriview y un boton para la consulta y probar mi codigo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Entidad;
using Negocio;

namespace Rsa
{
    public partial class frmPolizas : Form
    {
        public frmPolizas()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnListar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           List<POLIZAS> lista = new List<POLIZAS>();
           NPolizas nPolizas = new NPolizas();
           lista = nPolizas.GetPolizas();
           dgvPolizas.DataSource = lista;
        }
    }
}
```

y cuando presiono el boton Listar solo me muestra la cabecera y no me trae datos a pesar que tengo muchos registros en esta tabla?? Que estoy haciendo mal??

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora me sale un error como este
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al parecer dice que no encuentra cadena de conexion, sin embargo si tengo app.conf

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
La verdad ya no entiendo.

Gracias por cualquier ayuda que me puedan dar.

Comment: Hola, no tendrías que llamar a tu capa de negocio para rellenar tu lista? En el menejador del botón no lo estás haciendo, estás creando una lista vacía.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

viendo tu código lo que realmente se está haciendo es asignar a tu DGV una lista vacía. Deberías primero rellenar dicha lista llamando a tu componente de negocio. Cómo el método en negocio es estático no haría falta instanciar la clase.

```
    private void btnListar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<POLIZAS> lista = NPolizas.GetPolizas(); // llamar a negocio
        dgvPolizas.DataSource = lista;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir algo de contexto o explicación a tu código? Tal como está ahora, podría ser considerado como una respuesta de baja calidad ¡Gracias!

Comment: Como dice muriano, la respuestas que contienen sólo código no suelen ser bien consideradas.Simplemente con que añadieras el comentario que pusiste a OP en tu respuesta,ésta estaría mas completa. Tienes un problema además con tu código. `NPolizas` es una clase, asi que debes primero crear una instancia para poder llamar a `GetPolizas`, fíjate en el código de mi respuesta.

Comment: Ahora edito la respuesta. Nótese que el método GetPolizas() es static

Comment: Gracias por vuestras puntualizaciones.

Comment: Pues tienes toda la razón Sergio, es `static`. Borro mi respuesta ya que la tuya es correcta

Comment: ok gracias segui el consejo de Pikoh y funciono a la perfeccion. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Te está faltando el `app.config` en el proyecto principal, tiene que ir ahí también la conexión